# Object pronouns+verbs+ing

Tags: pronouns, gerunds

As non native speaker of English , I'm having trouble making sense of a structure pertaining to object pronouns.

> Likelihood of **me doing** this....
>
> Your plan involves **me attempting** to prepare plans necessary for you.
>
> Chances of **me getting into** that school is high.

What is it that establishes the connection between object pronouns and verbs in gerund form in terms of both grammar and meaning? In my language , expressions corresponding to the expressions in bold above are constituted with "my" instead of "me". That is the reason why I'm having trouble making sense of it.

Comment: Those are **Subject** pronouns. Gerund verb phrases (like _doing this, attempting to prepare plans necessary for you,_ and _getting into that school_) can have subjects, and those subject pronouns are in the objective form (i.e, _me_; they can also be in the possessive form, like _my doing this_); the only thing they **can't** be is nominative, like the subject of a tensed clause -- **of I doing this* is ungrammatical).

Comment: So what is the difference between "my doing this" and " me doing this"?

Comment: No meaning or grammar difference; speaker's choice. Some prefer one, some another, and many vary.

Comment: Damn! I spent years remembering to say 'my' instead of 'me', and now Professor Lawler tell me I was OK with 'me.

Answer (score 2):

In careful usage, people will generally use 'my' instead of 'me' in those cases, to emphasize that they are talking about the action rather than the person doing the action. However, in casual English you will hear 'me' and it usually means the exact same thing as 'my'.

Comment: So when what you said is applied to my examples ,   "chances of my getting into .." becomes correct one.Right?

Comment: Correct, although what you have currently is also acceptable.